# PHP: file_put_content echoing out warning

Tags: php

**Warning Code:**

```
Warning: file_put_contents(#C_H1_container { position:relative; min-height: 200px;} h1 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 30px; font-size: 4em; color: #000000; } h2 { position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 212px; font-size: 4em; color: #000000; z-index: 100; } #logo {position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 10px; z-index: 99; max-height: 195px;} #topright_link { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 20px; background: #423231; } #topright_link ul { font-size: .95em; line-height: .95em; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; } #topright_link ul li { display: block; position: relative; float: left; } #topright_link ul li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #fff; padding: 11px 25px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; min-width: 100px; } #topright_link ul li a:hover { background: #1e7c9a; color: #fff; } #topright_link li:hover a { background: #CCC; color: #000; } #navigation { position: absolute; top: 140px; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height: 45px; backgr in /home/kylej/public_html/style.php on line 13
```

**The Code**

```
$stylesheet_original = file_get_contents('www.domain.com/stylesheet.css');
$stylesheet_new = $_POST['stylesheet'];

if (isset($_POST['stylesheet'])) { 
file_put_contents($stylesheet_original, $stylesheet_new);
}

echo '
<form action="style.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="stylesheet" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;">'. $stylesheet_original .'</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
';
```

I have never really used file_put_contents before, and I can't find anything by googling my issue.  I'm just testing out being able to edit content in a textarea from a file and saving back to file.  If there is a better way, please share.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://php.net/file_put_contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change This:

```
if (isset($_POST['stylesheet'])) { 
  file_put_contents($stylesheet_original, $stylesheet_new);
}
```

To this:

```
if (isset($_POST['stylesheet'])) { 
  file_put_contents( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/stylesheet.css', $stylesheet_new);
}
```

[file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) accepts a file name as the first parameter.  You had a variable which contains the contents of the file we are replacing.

Comment: It now processes.  That was an overlook and thank you for noticing.  Can you tell me why its throwing this error: `Warning: file_put_contents(...stylesheet.css...): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home/***/public_html/stylesheet.css on line 14`

Comment: @kdjernigan your error is because 'www.domain.com/stylesheet.css' is a web address, and not a local file path.  If www.domain.com is same website that the php is executing on you can replace 'www.domain.com/stylesheet.css' with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/stylesheet.css'

Comment: You are very welcome and the reputation points just put over 500 for the first time, so thank you.